# Get a substring of a char*

Tags: c, char, substring

For example, I have this

```
char *buff = "this is a test string";
```

and want to get `"test"`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
char subbuff[5];
memcpy( subbuff, &buff[10], 4 );
subbuff[4] = '\0';
```

Job done :)

Comment: This will waste memory. You have been warned! :P

Comment: @alexandernst: How exactly?  5 bytes allocated on the stack (which will get freed when it drops out of scope) is hardly wasting memory ...

Comment: Still more than what you need, but yeah, they'll get free-ed as soon as the code leaves the current stack.

Comment: @alexandernst: The problem is that you can't do much with that string data without copying it.  If you take a pointer to the section from the original string you need to know the length as it will have no null terminator (Without affecting the original string).

Comment: Don't forget to #include <string.h>.

Comment: @Juampi: Is string.h really needed? You're only using arrays and memcpy.

Comment: @alexandernst: Couldn't you reuse the same buff?
`memcpy(buff, &buff[10], 4);`
`buff[4] = '\0';`

Comment: @TNT writing to pointer to string literal is undefined behavior. Your code crashes the program on my machine. See [this](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: subbuff[4] = '\0'; this is very important, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 109):

Assuming you know the position and the length of the substring:

```
char *buff = "this is a test string";
printf("%.*s", 4, buff + 10);
```

You could achieve the same thing by copying the substring to another memory destination, but it's not reasonable since you already have it in memory.

This is a good example of avoiding unnecessary copying by using pointers.

Comment: @procrastinator: Not really only for printing. This is a viable approach in case the substring is not going to be modified. This way you simply keep a pair of pointers instead of allocating a variable-length buffer.

Comment: N̶i̶c̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶p̶r̶i̶n̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶̶̶̶y̶ Sorry if you got me wrong, I mean that your solution doesn't require an extra string, which is perfect when you only need to print :-)

Comment: use sprintf to store the above formatted string

Comment: @ParnabSanyal how can I use sprintf to store the substring? Do I need to pass substring length as third parameter?

Comment: @VermaAman no you don't. Your first argument would be the resulting string, second argument would be the source string and if you have placeholders inside second argument like `%c`, `%i` etc then from third argument to upto the number of placeholders, would be the actual values of the placeholder( comma separated). Just like `printf`

Answer (score 71):

Use `char* strncpy(char* dest, char* src, int n)` from `<cstring>`. In your case you will need to use the following code:

```
char* substr = malloc(4);
strncpy(substr, buff+10, 4);
```

Full documentation on the `strncpy` function [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/).

Comment: don't forget to add the null-termination character '\0' if you do this.

Comment: don't forget to malloc the substr large enough if you do this.

Comment: ```
char *substr(char const *s, size_t start, size_t length)
{
    char *substr = calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char));
    strncpy(substr, s + start, length);

    return substr;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `strstr`. Example code [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/).

Note that the returned result is not null terminated.

Comment: This is kind of the reverse of a normal substring operation - more like indexOf.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `strstr()` from `<string.h>`

[$ man strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

Comment: See Grault's comment down below

Comment: @Barmar: So in your definition what is substring?

Comment: @Rainning A substring is any contiguous portion of a string. E.g. `def` is a substring of `abcdefghi`

Comment: @Barmar: Then since `strstr()` return the first index of the substring it found, but you said it's not just the substring.

Comment: The question asked how to get `test` from `this is a test string`. This answer would return `test string`, not just `test`.

Comment: Yes it is a substring, but it's limited to substrings that reach the end, it doesn't work if you want shorter substrings as in the question.