# Parent directory of a file

Tags: c

Is there any way to find out the parent directory of a file using C program. I would like to give same permissions for the file that the directory has. So as to do so, i would like to know the parent directory of the file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From string? From file descriptor?

Comment: A file can have more than 1 parent directory: see `man ln` in Linux, junction point or whatever in Windows (`mklink /?` works on my Windows Vista)

Comment: If you don't give it any permissions, it will inherit those of the directory.

Comment: i dont want to know the entire hierarchy..only the bottom most

Comment: @pmg yeah lucky us, we've got real symlinks now on Windows!!

Comment: @David Not to start an argument, but you can't `cd` into a junction directory, so I wouldn't say they're real :-P

Comment: Which operating system and file system are you using? Standard C does not provide what you want.

Comment: @Jonathan That's junctions. You are behind the times. We do have symlinks now in Windows 7. And you can cd into a junction directory as make by `junction`. It just did so.

Comment: @David Neat! Last I tried, it told me it couldn't, but that was about a year ago in Vista.

Comment: @Jonathan I've never seen that, way back to win2k, but who knows with junctions. They are a bit weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such function  in Standard C. You may try your luck on Windows with [`GetFullPathName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and then maybe [`_splitpath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

But as written there's not standard function for doing such kind of things.

Comment: Actually on Windows you would join a .. to the end of the string and then call `PathCanonicalize()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the path of the file, you can do it manually by making it an absolute path if it is relative (doesn't begin with a `/` on Unix, or a `letter:\` or `\` or `letter:/` or `/` on Windows) and then splitting it on file separator characters (`/` or `\`), but I am aware of no built-in function that will do all of this for you.

The [`basename` and `dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) functions may help, but you'll need to figure out enough of the path of the file yourself, as they only work with strings; they do not interrogate the file system.

Answer (score 4):

It's not guaranteed to do *The Right Thing*, but have you tried any of the following:

- If your filename contains a path separator (e.g. `/` on Unix, `\` on Windows), copy the string using e.g. `strdup()` and replace the last occurence of the path separator (found with e.g. `strrchr()`) with a zero/null character. The resulting string will be the parent directory of your file.
- If there is no path separator, then the file resides within your current working directory. Have you tried just using `.`? The `.` and `..` links work on both Unix and Windows.

There are quite a few corner cases above (e.g. what of the file `/hello.txt`?), but it should be a start.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a C language snippet using codes from [cplusplus web page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/), [Goz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4214350/5595995) and [thkala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5393222/5595995).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
.
.
.
    out_file_name = "c:/Users/Documents/output/test.txt";
    const char ch = '/'; 
    char* rest;
    int loc; 
    char letter;
    char* pointer_to_loc; 

    // Current directory
    rest = strrchr(out_file_name, ch);
    // Just make sure there is a directory
    if (rest != NULL) {
        pointer_to_loc = strrchr(out_file_name, ch);  # Pointer to last / symbol
        loc = rest - out_file_name + 1;
        char subbuff[loc]; # string for truncated string
        loc--;
        memcpy( subbuff, &out_file_name[0], loc ); # copy section of string
        subbuff[loc] = '\0';

        // Parent directory, now input is current directory from previous section
        rest = strrchr(subbuff, ch);
        if (rest != NULL) {
            loc = rest - subbuff + 1;
            char subsubbuff[loc];
            loc--;
            memcpy( subsubbuff, &subbuff[0], loc );
            subsubbuff[loc] = '\0';

            printf (subsubbuff); // Parent directory
            printf ("\n");
        }
        printf (subbuff); // Current directory
        printf ("\n");
    }
    printf (output_file_name); // Entire path to file
```