# How to get parent Directory in C programming?

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to do this in C programming without using string manipulation especially since the path contains a mix of forward and backward slashes.

```
path = "C:\Program Files\PTC/Creo 4.0/M040/Parametric/bin/parametric.exe";
var searchDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)));
```

The path is char array.

```
char InstallExe[MAX_PATH_LENGTH].
```

The output I am expecting is

```
searchDir = "C:\Program Files\PTC/Creo 4.0/M040"
```

Comment: Are you looking for a C standard library function or a function in the Windows API?

Comment: Any of them should work for me. I am working on a C application which is on Windows platform.

Comment: I tried Google and found this almost at the top: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392735/parent-directory-of-a-file?rq=1 Does that answer help?

Comment: Since you've tagged `winapi` you can use `PathRemoveFileSpec` from `shlwapi.dll`.

Comment: the standard APIs are `dirname` and `pathname`.  Have you tried them on Windows?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Unfortunately, `PathRemoveFileSpec` doesn't handle foreslashes. `"C:\\abc/def/ghi"` becomes `"C:\\abc"`

Comment: what is wrong with a simple search for the last `/` or ` \ ` ?

Comment: also win32 name can containing `/../` for example - need first normalize name by `GetFullPathName` and than call `PathRemoveFileSpec` or yourself remove last \ which is aloso simply

Comment: @RbMm Thank you for your help. I tried below code 

`char SearchFolder[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
GetFullPathNameA(path, dwDataSize, SearchFolder, &string);
PathRemoveFileSpecA(SearchFolder);`
Output of GetFullPathNameA statement is
`D:\Builds\OSApp\x64\Debug\"C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 4.0\M040\Parametric\bin\parametric.exe"`
Output of PathRemoveFileSpecA is
`D:\Builds\OSApp\x64\Debug\"C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 4.0\M040\Parametric\bin`
What I want is 
`C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 4.0\M040\Parametric\bin`
How do I strip the initial path of the calling application?

Comment: you pass wrong file path to `GetFullPathName` - it must not containing ". use for example `GetModuleFileNameW`. and stop use A api. use only W