# How can I get a word from string

Tags: c++, c

I have f.e. "I am working as a nurse."
How Can I or which function use to get word from letter number 1 to space or to letter number 11?

So should I get " am working "

Comment: you want 1 word or 2 words?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, especially when it comes to strings; make a choice. If C++: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/, if C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char

Comment: Look into `string::substr`.

Comment: I mean every char between declared position

Comment: @Marcin - Have another go at writing the question. Does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not totally clear what you want, but from your example it seems like you want the substring that starts at character 1 and ends on the character 11 places later (that's 12 characters total). That means you want `string::substr`:

```
std::string str("I am working as a nurse");
std::string sub = str.substr(1,12);
```

Comment: I'd think they wanted the 11th character, which is 10 later.

Comment: @chris The result they give as an example, " am working ", starts at character 1 and ends at character 12. Actually, that would need `substr(1,12)`. Yeah, the question makes no sense.

Comment: Oops, I counted 11 before. You're right. Maybe it's supposed to finish the word it's on?

Comment: @chris And include the next space? :D

Answer (score 9):

To read a word from a stream use operator>> on a string

```
std::stringstream  stream("I am working as a nurse.");
std::string  word;

stream >> word;  // word now holds 'I'
stream >> word;  // word now holds 'am'
stream >> word;  // word now holds 'working'
// .. etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] source = "I am working as a nurse."
char[11] dest;
strncpy(dest, &source[1], 10)
```