# How to use internal (private) function in NDK

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

How do I create and use an internal function in an ndk c++ file?

```
jstring Java_com_test_ndk_MainActivity_getString(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    jstring strt = getstr();
    return env->NewStringUTF(strt);
}
```

I want to implement the `getstr()` function in c++ for just use in ndk side and not java...

Also, how do I get the length of a jstring and implement substring in c++? Does a function exist or must I write my own?

Comment: what is `getstr`? Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: that's solved, you have any idea for substring char ?

Comment: like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char ?

Comment: want to utf8 substring ...

Answer (score 0):

Just declare and define it:

```
jstring getstr()
{
   jstring result;

   // do something useful here

   return result;
}
```