# how to get substring from a bigger string in c?

Tags: c, string, substring

when in java we can use

```
sting_name.substring(start, end);
```

to get a new substring

```
    String full_line = "this is a simple line.";
    String part_line;
    System.out.println(full_line);
    part_line = full_line.substring(10, 16);
    System.out.println(part_line);
```

how can do that same thing in c? is there any function similar to substring?

```
char full_line[] = "this is a simple line" ;
char part_line[20];
printf("\n%s\n",full_line);
//part_line ;
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic and `memcpy()`. [Example](https://github.com/H2CO3/Sparkling/blob/master/src/rtlb.c#L660-694).

Comment: use `strncpy` for substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get a substring of a char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char)

after looking at above link I tried this:
just want to make sure if this is correct way of doing this or there is downside of this?

```
char full_line[] = "this is a simple line" ;
char part_line[20];
printf("\n%s\n",full_line);
memcpy( part_line, &full_line[10], 6);
part_line[6+1] = '\0';
printf("\n%s\n",part_line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [strncpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strncpy.htm)

Example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char src[40];
   char dest[12];

   memset(dest, '\0', sizeof(dest));
   strcpy(src, "This is tutorialspoint.com");
   strncpy(dest, src+2, 10);

   printf("Final copied string : %s\n", dest);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why is everyone casting the return value of `malloc()`...!?

Comment: This answer is *very* wrong. (in fact: almost every use of strncpy() is wrong)

Comment: @H2CO3 - it was just the first example I grabbed.  I changed it to a more straight forward example

Comment: also, was the original version plagiarized from the other answer or vice versa? They had the same content up until very recently.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Yes I googled it, didnt write it myself.  I thought this question was going to be closed quickly so I wanted to give the OP an answer he could use before it did.

Comment: In the new version you manage to perform *three* passes over the string just to copy (part of) it.

Comment: @wildplasser - Feel free to edit it.  The answer to his question is `strncpy`  I just tried to provide a little context before the question is closed.

Comment: I don't edit other peoples submissions. But I strongly object to any usage of strncpy().

Comment: @wildplasser - Post your solution as an answer.  More than 1 way to skin a cat.