# Access to a value pointed by pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, access-violation

I have the following code:

```
    char * transfer_encoding;
    char coso;
    if (transfer_encoding = strstr(first_chunk.content, "Transfer-Encoding:")){

        coso = *(transfer_encoding + 18);
        printf(" %s ", coso);
}
```

It just search for the string "Transfer-Encoding:" and then tries to access to the value after the ":" (18=len("Transfer-Encoding:")). It gives me an access violation reading the address 0x0000020. Why? 
I want to walk through the bytes after "Transfer-Encoding" to find a "\r\n".

To clarify the question. I want to walk through the bytes AFTER "Transfer-Encoding" to find a "\r\n". How can I do it? 
Thank you.

Comment: You're lying to your compiler. You say `%s`, but then fail to provide a pointer to a char. You should probably look for a better, more modern compiler that will give you a helpful warning for this kind of mistake.

Comment: @KerrekSB   +1 For "lying to your compiler" line.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char
nicely answered there.

Comment: @KerrekSB meh... the compiler won't diagnose various other printf problems,  at some point you have to say: read the instructions that came with your tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take the address after `Transfer-Encoding:`

```
transfer_encoding + 18
```

dereference it

```
coso = *(transfer_encoding + 18);
```

and try to interpret it as a string

```
printf(" %s ", coso);
```

The correct way would be

```
printf(" %s ", transfer_encoding + 18);
```

without dereferencing it.

---

The address `0x0000020` comes from the character after the colon, which is usually a space. This is `32` or `0x20` in ASCII.

---

If you want to look at the content of that address, it is perfectly valid to dereference the pointer, e.g.

```
char cr = *(transfer_encoding + 18);
char nl = *(transfer_encoding + 18 + 1);
if (cr == '\r' && nl = '\n')
    printf("CRLF found\n");
```

To compare a whole string, you can also use [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) or [`strncmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html)

```
if (strncmp(transfer_encoding + 18, "\r\n", 2) == 0)
    printf("CRLF found\n");
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I do something like if(transfer_encoding + 18=='\r') if (transfer_encoding + 18 +1=='\n') printf("well done"); ??

Comment: The problem is not the dereferencing, but the reinterpretation of that character as a pointer. If you want to compare the content of that address with some character, you can dereference the pointer as long as it is valid, of course.

Comment: I have been trying so many ways. Can you paste just how to compare a memory address byte with '\n' for example? then I will code the rest to iterate through all the bytes. Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I have a negative vote but thanks anyway

Comment: @Alberto you may find the syntax `transfer_encoding[18]` (instead of `*(transfer_encoding + 18)` more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

The compiler probably warned you about this code.

You hold the character after colon instead of pointing there:

```
char *transfer_encoding;
char *coso;
if (transfer_encoding = strstr(first_chunk.content, "Transfer-Encoding:"))
{
    coso = transfer_encoding + 18;
    printf(" %s ", coso);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function strstr returns null when the string "Transfer-Encoding:" is not present in the content, when this happens you get an access violation. Try checking if the pointer is not null before continuing like this:

```
   char * transfer_encoding;
   char * coso;
   if ((transfer_encoding = strstr(first_chunk.content, "Transfer-Encoding:"))){
     if (transfer_encoding != NULL){
        coso = transfer_encoding + 18;
        printf(" %s ", coso);
     }
   }
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Excellent then, you have another problem with the pointer, you are explicitly taking 1 character out of the string instead of getting the pointer to whatever is left in the string, try again please

Comment: Thanks but it is not NULL

Comment: Your cast is bad ... take it out