# Removing start of char array at last occurrence of a character C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, trim

I am looking for the best way to remove the start of a string until the last occurrence of a character.  For example. I have a char array that contains the following:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Option 'enable_debug_reports' requires a value of 0 or 1.

Basically, I am looking for the last occurrence of ']'. I would like my char array to be trimmed to:

> Option 'enable_debug_reports' requires a value of 0 or 1.

I have found several ways to do this with the string data type.  I am wondering if there is an effective way to manipulate a char array.  My program requires several parameters to be char[] instead of strings.  How would I use something like `strcpy` in my situation?

Comment: If you want to work with `std::string`s but need to use some functions that take `const char *`, you can use `myString.c_str()`.

Comment: I wish for my question to deal specifically with char[].  Thank you for your suggestion.  I am, however, wondering if the same thing can be done without using `std::string` or any casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work provided your string does contain the ']' character:

```cpp
std::string trimIt(originalCStr);
std::string trimmed(trimIt.substr(trimIt.find_last_of("]")));
strcpy(originalCStr, trimmed.c_str());
```

For a pure C approach:

```cpp
char *toPtr = originalCStr;
char *fromPtr = strchr(toPtr, ']');
++fromPtr;
while (*fromPtr != '\0') {
    *toPtr = *fromPtr;
    ++fromPtr;
    ++toPtr;
}
*toPtr = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use [strrchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/) to find the last occurrence of ']' and then cut your char[] using [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char)

Comment: `memmove` if the copy is in the same buffer. and potentially (or actually) overlaps. Or just a plain-old `dst` and `src` pointer loop through the terminator.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on not using `std::string`, for whatever reason, there is still a pure C++ approach using standard **algorithms**, which work just fine with raw arrays. The following is C++14 (it uses `std::rbegin` and `std::rend`), but you can adapt it to C++11 using `std::reverse_iterator` manually if necessary:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <class InputRange, class OutputIterator, class Value>
void CopyFrom(InputRange const& input, OutputIterator output_iter, Value const& value)
{
    using std::rbegin;
    using std::rend;
    using std::end;

    auto const iter_last = std::find(rbegin(input), rend(input), value);
    std::copy(iter_last.base(), end(input), output_iter);
}

int main()
{
    char const src[] = "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Option 'enable_debug_reports' requires a value of 0 or 1.";
    char * dst = new char[sizeof(src) + 1](); // just for this toy program

    CopyFrom(src, dst, ']');

    std::cout << dst;
    delete[] dst;
}
```

Note that this solution assumes that you need the substring as a *copy*, and there is no error checking for input that does not contain the specified value.

And of course, you are probably better of switching to `std::string` and using `c_str()` for any C APIs.