# Get the beginning of a string until a given char

Tags: c

I know that is a simple question but I couldn't find the answer.

I have this string:

```
"M1[r2][r3]"
```

I want to get only the `"M1"`, I'm looking for something like `strchr()`
a function that get the string and a `char` to stop at.

Comment: what do you mean by `string`? how `M1` was declared?

Comment: @CIsForCookies I think `"M1[r2][r3]"` is the content of the string.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca  Like you said, "M1[r2][r3]" is the string

Comment: Show some other strings and which part of them you want, otherwise the answer is `printf("M1");`.

Comment: Try this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114377/strings-in-c-how-to-get-substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114377/strings-in-c-how-to-get-substring) Or this:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char) Hope this helps.

Comment: Use [strtok()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) to tokenize strings based on a separator like `"["`.

Comment: @AndreKampling I was writing this answer and only after that saw your comment :(

Comment: The question is unclear. Is the code the declaration or the string itself? If it is the string, then why can't you use strchr as you propose yourself?

Comment: I thought this isn't a "write my code" site? The question is very poor quality.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree. This isn't even trying.

Comment: `char id[8]; sscanf("M1[r2][r3]", " %7[^[]", id);` (`int len = 0; sscanf("M1[r2][r3]", " %7[^[][%n", id, &len);`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about using [`strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) and `"["` as a delimiter?

```
#include <string.h> /* for strtok */
#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf */
int main()
{
    char str[] = "M1[r2][r3]"; // str will be modified by strtok
    const char deli[] = "[";   // deli could also be declared as [2] or as const char *. Take your pick...
    char *token;

    token = strtok(str, deli); // can also call strtok(str, "["); and not use variable deli at all
    printf("%s", token);       // printf("%s", str); will print the same result

    /* OUTPUT: M1 */

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: You should mention that `strtok()` changes the input buffer so that printing `str` will be `"M1"` too because every separator will be replaced by a null terminator. Further no `[2]` is needed use just `[]`.

Comment: I don't get why this answer get downvotes. Yes it isn't a "write the code for me" site but the answer isn't wrong or lacks in quality. I would say if somebody isn't comfortable with an answer to such a question he/she shouldn't upvote but also not downvote.

Comment: I agree that `[]` will be ok, but why not use `[2]`? I think of it as a reminder (especially for beginners) that "[" is a string literal that has 2 `char`

Comment: @ClsForCookies: Ah I didn't saw it that way :D. I was just thinking don't repeat yourself.

Comment: @AndreKampling it is usually considered [**unhelpful**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to supply a pat answer to "gimme the code" questions.

Comment: I hope I'm not overstepping my bounds, but from my experience, when I was doing my first steps here at SO, these were the answers that were most helpful for me. I got to learn about new functions and how someone else would achieve my question goal. If the OP wasn't a noob here, my answer would be different

Comment: @CIsForCookies  nice answer, +1, but please include the headers needed, some users might not be aware of them (although they can see it in the ref, but...).

Answer (score 3):

> something like strchr() a function that get the string and a char to stop at.

If only a printing of the sub-string is needed, use `strcspn()` which finds the offset when `'['` first occurs, (or the end if not found).  This does not alter the source string.

```
const char *s = "M1[r2][r3]";
printf("%.*s\n", (int) strcspn(s, "["), s);
```

Output

```
M1
```

Comment: Beautiful function.

Comment: @jav Thanks - but it did have the wrong type - answer amended.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and the character to stop (a delimeter, in your case `[`) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="M1[r2][r3]";
  printf ("Getting M1 from \"%s\":\n",str);
  strtok (str,"[");
  if (str != NULL)
    printf ("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Getting M1 from "M1[r2][r3]":
M1
```

---

However, if you know the length of the substring, you should see [Get a substring of a char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214314/get-a-substring-of-a-char).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) like this:

```
char subStr[3];
sscanf("M1[r2][r3]", " %2[^[]", subStr);
```

where `[^[]` means a character except `[` and 2 guards the length of the string written into the substring (it's equal to `subStr`'s size - 1, so that space for the NULL terminator is available).

as BLUEPIXY suggested.